# ASP.NET MVC minifying one line of javascript code out of 2500 lines causes error

Tags: javascript, asp.net

#### Installed product versions

- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.8.2
- Bundler: 2.8.396

This line of code with braces causes an error:

```
var vparms = { iworkoutname, row };
```

This minifies successfully:

```
var vparms = { };
```

This also throws an error:

```
av = 0;
bv = 0;
var vparms = {av, bv};
```

So it doesn't look like the variables are the issue.

> In case you're wondering:
> `iworkoutname` = jagged array of objects,
> `row` = int

Here's my traceback:

```sh
processing ../Content/mbsaMinify.css.bundle:
writing ../Content/mbsaMinify.css...
processing ../Scripts/mbsaMinify.js.bundle:
minifying ..\Scripts\mbsaAngularMinifyPerformWorkout.min.js...
{
  message: 'Unexpected token punc, expected punc',
  line: 138,
  col: 39,
  pos: 6376,
  stack: 'Error: 
    at new JS_Parse_Error (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:260:22)
    at js_error  (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:268:15)
    at croak (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:717:17)
    at token_error (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:724:17)
    at expect_token (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:737:17)
    at expect (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:740:40)
    at object_ (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1134:33)
    at D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1086:51
    at maybe_unary (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1185:27)
    at expr_ops (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1212:32)
    at maybe_conditional (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1216:28)
    at maybe_assign (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1240:28)
    at D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1254:28
    at vardefs (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1041:48)
    at var_ (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1053:34)
    at prog1 (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1288:23)
    at D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:859:40
    at block_ (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:979:32)
    at D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:958:43
    at D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:962:29
    at D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1092:43
    at maybe_unary (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1185:27)
    at expr_ops (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1212:32)
    at maybe_conditional (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1216:28)
    at maybe_assign (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1240:28)
    at D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1254:28
    at object_ (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1135:48)
    at D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1086:51
    at maybe_unary (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1185:27)
    at expr_ops (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1212:32)
    at maybe_conditional (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1216:28)
    at maybe_assign (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1240:28)
    at D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1254:28
    at prog1 (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1288:23)
    at D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:845:45
    at block_ (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:979:32)
    at D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:958:43
    at D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:962:29
    at D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1092:43
    at maybe_unary (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1185:27)
    at expr_ops (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1212:32)
    at maybe_conditional (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1216:28)
    at maybe_assign (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1240:28)
    at D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1254:28
    at expr_list (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1111:40)
    at subscripts (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1174:60)
    at subscripts (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1166:32)
    at D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1098:32
    at maybe_unary (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1185:27)
    at expr_ops (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1212:32)
    at maybe_conditional (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1216:28)
    at maybe_assign (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1240:28)
    at D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1254:28
    at prog1 (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1288:23)
    at simple_statement (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:886:35)
    at D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:794:35
    at D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1273:32
    at Object.parse (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\lib\parse-js.js:1275:11)
    at minifyjs (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\bundler.js:520:19) 
    at D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\bundler.js:421:12
    at Function.<anonymous> (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\bundler.js:497:17)
    at next (D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\node_modules\step\lib\step.js:51:23)
    at D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\bundler\bundler.js:481:25
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
  '
}
```

Thanks for any advice or solutions.

Comment: I know this is valid: `var vparms = { iworkoutname, row };`, but I'm wondering something. Can you try `var vparms = { "iworkoutname" :iworkoutname , "row" : row };`